# _beginthread/ex C3861 - identifier not found

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008

Here is my test code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "iostream" 
using namespace std;

HANDLE hMutex;

static unsigned __stdcall threadFunc(void *params)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(hMutex,INFINITE);
    printf(":D:D:D\n");
    ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
    return NULL;    
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
        hMutex=CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,NULL);
        //first try
        unsigned dwChildId;
        _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &threadFunc, NULL, 0, &dwChildId);
        //second try
        _beginthread(threadFunc, 0, NULL );
        WaitForSingleObject(hMutex,INFINITE);
        printf("HD\n");
        ReleaseMutex(hMutex);
        int i;
        cin >> i;
    return 0;
}
```

Gives me 2 errors :

```
Error   1   error C3861: '_beginthreadex': identifier not found 
Error   2   error C3861: '_beginthread': identifier not found
```

I am using MFC as shared DLL. Also i dont know how to create two threads with same function.

After i included 'process.h'

```
Error   2   error C2664: '_beginthread' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void *)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_beginthread` and `_beginthreadex` require different types of functions.  `_beginthread` requires a cdecl function; `_beginthreadex` requires a stdcall function.

On x86, where cdecl and stdcall are different, you cannot use a single thread procedure with both `_beginthread` and `_beginthreadex` (on x64 and ARM, there is only one calling convention, so stdcall and cdecl mean the same thing and are not necessary).

That said:  Do not use `_beginthread`.  Instead, use `_beginthreadex`, and make sure to close the handle that it returns.  [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx) adequately explains the shortcomings of `_beginthread` and why `_beginthreadex` is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

You're [missing the appropriate header and/or you're not using the multithreaded C run-time libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
/* Routine: _beginthreadex
 * Required header: process.h
 */
#include <process.h>
```

Comment: Now this `Error 2 error C2664: '_beginthread' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void *)'`

Comment: The error seems self explanatory, and is unrelated to this question. You can ask a new question to get that bit solved.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) suggest it is in process.h, so you need

```
#include <process.h>
```

Note that `""` searches a different path to `<>`

Answer (score 1):

Make your `threadFunc` match the required signature!  (replace  __stdcall to __cdecl ) and make it void... until it is a match

Comment: on `_beginthread(threadFunc, 0, NULL );`: `Error 1 error C2664: '_beginthread' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'unsigned int (__cdecl *)(void *)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(void *)'`

Answer (score 0):

Or there can be another `<process.h>` header from a different library somewhere on include path shadowing `<process.h>` from the Boost library.